# CSS height:auto for all types except SVG

Tags: css

don't know if it is possible, but I'd like to scale all images on my site with the following:

```
.myClass img {
    height: auto;
}
```

However, all *.svg-files shouldn't match that pattern. Is there a way to do this via native css?

I found something like this:

```
.myClass img[src$=".svg"] {height: auto;}
```

But that seems to trigger only for svg-files. Trying to use **!=** seems to be syntactically incorrect.

Comment: For what it's worth, you could just inline the `svg` files instead of including them via the `img` tag? Then you would customize them in `css` by using `svg` instead of `img`

Comment: The problem is, that this is in a Typo3 context and the user may insert svg-files via an RTE-editor.

Comment: Try `.myClass img:not([src$=".svg"]){...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you'll want to refer to the attribute-selector.

Example:

```
.myclass[src$=".svg"]
```

Reference;
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Edit;
Just saw your edit.
In css you can also use a :not(selector)

example:

```
.myclass:not([src$=".svg"]);
```

Comment: That does it :) Thanks as well to @Vucko. Will accept this asap :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.myClass img {
  height: auto;
}
.myClass img[src$=svg i] {
  height: 100px;
}
```

first set height to all images, then reset the setting for all images having src with suffix svg case insensitively